# Getting list of zeros in model.fit for Logistic regression classifier in sklearn python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, naivebayes

I am running Logistic regression classifier on a dataset like this:

```
ID| feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | Match
0 |   6      |    9     |  9.5     |   1 
1 |   9      |    7     |  3.9     |   0
2 |   7      |    3     |  5.8     |   1
```

My model is `y(match) = f(feature1, feature2, feature3)` where y is a binary variable. I am running the following code in python:

```
df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv', encoding = 'latin-1')
X = pd.DataFrame()
X['match'] = df ['match']
X['feature1'] = df ['feature1']
X['feature2'] = df ['feature2']
X['feature3'] = df ['feature3']

X = X.dropna(axis=0)  # Drop NAs
y = X['match'].to_frame() # Categorical variable Match [Yes, No]
y = np.ravel(y) # Converting into 1-D array
X = X.drop(['match'], axis=1) # Drop y from X
X = X.as_matrix() # converting dataframe to numpy matrix

# Splitting into training and testing data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Applying logistic regression using sklearn
model_1 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1)
model_1.fit(X_train, y_train)
model_1.predict(X_test)
```

The above code returns [0,0,0 ... , 0,0,0] for model_1.predict(X_test). I have checked at many places but I have found no mistake in my code. Also it runs but gives unexpected results. Please help.

Comment: What is the expected output that it should return according to you? Normalized Probability of each class calculated using the logistic function?

Comment: I want the output to be in the format of classification i.e. for example [1,0,0,0,1 ... ,0,1,0]

Comment: I am getting output in the similar format but the values are all zeros in the list i.e. [0,0,0 ... , 0,0,0] which is not correct.

Comment: It correctly predicts for me. It gives 1 as the output prediction for `X_test=[6  9 9.5]`. If you want the probability estimates of each label, I'd suggest using `predict_proba`.

Comment: I am getting the probability estimates and they look fine to me but still getting list zeros in the classification. It was also possible that it somehow classified all the testing set into zeros so to test this I run the SVM and Naive Bayes as well but they both also returning list of zeros in their classification. How is it possible that I am getting exactly same accuracy from all the classifiers ? And most importantly all zeros, If only one element in the list classified 1 then i would though my results correct but I think i am doing something wrong. :(

Comment: I can't say much without having a look at the entire dataset. But for the portion of the data that you had posted, it works fine.

Comment: I got it solved. Actually the list of zeros was exactly the list I was getting. When I add further parameters in the model then it started to give 1s as well :) Thanks a lot man!