# model predicts class not in target (array of zeros)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have encoded my target variable using a MultiLabelBinarizer. I have then created a new DataFrame out of the result of the transform this way

```
y_trans = pd.DataFrame(MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y))
```

here is the `head()`

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I create the train and test sets using

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_trans, y_trans, random_state=0)
```

After fitting either a `RandomForest` or a `KNN`, predicting the `X_test` variable returns an array where some predictions are like this

```
array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

Such class is not present in the encoded target variable, as the result of

```
len(y_trans.where(y_trans == [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]).dropna())
```

is in fact 0.

I don't get why this happens.
[Somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958199/getting-list-of-zeros-in-model-fit-for-logistic-regression-classifier-in-sklearn).

### Reproduce my issue

I provide the [encoded features and labels](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FwMlb85Tq7Gh_JsPbfRdH_X_1fTu9Htn) to be downloaded. They have been pickled in binary format.
From there, the steps to reproduce my error are as simple as

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle

X_trans = pickle.load(open('features.pkl', 'rb'))
y_trans = pickle.load(open('target.pkl', 'rb'))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_trans, y_trans, random_state=0)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(rfc.predict(X_test)[1])
```

Printing the second value in the predictions will return `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

### My classification goal

My goal is to create a classifier that can predict at least one of the "correct classes", represented by the 1 in an entry.
For example, the first entry of y is `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]`.
I will consider correct

- `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`
- `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]`

but that is an evaluation concern that will take place once the predictions come out correct. As I said, there cannot be "empty" predictions. There are 18 classes and 127 unique combinations, none of which are `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.

### Sklearn [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn-multioutput-multioutputclassifier) have this same "issue"

At this point, this output has to have a meaning. But I can't figure it out.
Note: in this example, the classifier used is `KNN`, I showed `RandomForest` but if I were to use `KNN`, I would get the same issue.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=18, random_state=0)
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()).fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X)[3]

>>> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Same applies when splitting into train and test sets

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=18, random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict(X_test)[8]

>>> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for the quality of the question.

I think there is several things to explain here :

- Your classification goal : you need to define your own metric to measure what you describe. (see [make_scorer function in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html)). This is the first step, because you can't improve a model if you can't measure what an improvement is.
- Next, when training a model, you need to tune the model parameters (called hyper-parameters) to optimize your score. To explain quickly, you choose a set of parameters, train your model, and check the score on the test set. You iterate by modifying your parameters to optimize the test score. A simple way to do that is with [sklearn's GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).
- Now, to answer your question : your model is predicting for each of your 18 classes independently whether a sample is in this class or not. That's why on some cases, you can have a sample that doesn't seem to belong in any classes.

What can you do about it ?

- First, you will need to check if your model is fitting properly, and adjust hyper-parameters to improve the score. At the moment, it is over-fitting badly (training score is way higher that test score). You may find out that you don't have enough signal in your data to make it work properly at all.
- Maybe another model can help you get better results, depending on the topology of your data (you need to try and see)
- You can also get the predicted probabilities for each class with `rfc.predict_proba` : that will allow you to set a different threshold than the default 0.5, or even select the higher one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I'll have to define my own scoring function, but since I can't have good (meaningful) predictions, I can't continue. I have tried KNN, RF and SVC but none gave good results. Also GridSearch, let run for 30min, but no big improvements. I'm stuck, sklearn examples seem not to help either.

Comment: Choosing a model and optimizing improve results, but the best improvements will come from better input data (better features, meaning adding features, improve encoding, and so on). A good score is 90% data, 10% model optimization. My advice would be : first define your score, second implement a basic randomforest model like you did, and third get better features to improve score. But sometimes you just don't have enough signal to get significant results. Can you classify manually with your input features ? If not, you may not be able to do it with ML